# problem in installing mysqlworkbench 6

Tags: installation, 13.04, package-management, dpkg, mysql-workbench

Ubuntu 13.04 - 32 bit

```
(Reading database ... 216964 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking mysql-workbench-community (from mysql-workbench-community-6.0.6-1ubu1304-i386.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing mysql-workbench-community-6.0.6-1ubu1304-i386.deb (--install):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/mysql-workbench/model_view.glade', which is also in package mysql-workbench-data 5.2.40+dfsg-2ubuntu1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-workbench-community-6.0.6-1ubu1304-i386.deb
```

Please help..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Purged old package with:

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-workbench*
```

and installed new package with flag `--force-all` as below:

```
sudo dpkg --force-all -i mysql-workbench-community-6.0.6-1ubu1204-i386.deb
```

and it solved my problem.